# Error: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'

Tags: python, django

I am using python-3.11.2 with a Django project. I'm attempting to uploading my code to heroku and got the error: "Error: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'"

The stack:

```
"2023-05-02T05:27:02.843872+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
2023-05-02T05:27:02.972430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-05-02T05:27:03.011797+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-05-02T06:56:14.573979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-05-02T06:56:32.070764+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Albion.wsgi --log-file - -b 0.0.0.0:51852 -w 4`
```

My requirements:

```
asgiref==3.6.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
distlib==0.3.6
dj-database-url==1.2.0
Django==3.2.18
django-heroku==0.3.1
filelock==3.9.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
platformdirs==3.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.5
pytz==2022.7.1
requests==2.28.2
sqlparse==0.4.3
typing-extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.14
virtualenv==20.20.0
whitenoise==6.4.0
zipp==3.15.0
django-bootstrap4
gunicorn
```

I'm not sure what is off. Could someone assist?

Comment: Please show the full stack trace in your question. You should also include the part of your code that appears to be causing the error, if you can identify it.

Comment: [Python3.11 Removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#removed): The `getargspec()` function, deprecated since Python 3.0; use [`inspect.signature()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) or [`inspect.getfullargspec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) instead.

Comment: You may want to choose an older version to make it work with Heroku. 3.10 works just fine. 3.11 doesn't supports inspect.getargspec anymore.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i have added the trace